# C++ Linked List printing

Tags: c++, null, linked-list

Here is the code for a function that prints a LinkedList in a forward direction.

```
void DLinkedList::printForwards(int age)
{
DNode * current;
current = header->next;
while (current != NULL)
{
    if (current->elem->getAge() <= age) {
        cout << current->elem->getName() << ", ";
    }
    current = current->next;
}
cout << endl;
}
```

Here is the class DNode

```
typedef Person* Elem;
class DNode {                                 // doubly linked list node
private:
    Elem elem;                                  // node element value
    DNode* prev;                            // previous node in list
    DNode* next;                                // next node in list
    friend class DLinkedList;                   // allow DLinkedList access
};
```

Here is the class Person

```
class Person {                                 
public:
Person(int age, string first, string last){
    setAge(age);
    setFirstname(first);
    setLastName(last);
}
void setAge(int age){
    this->age = age;
}
void setFirstname(string first){
    firstName = first;
}
void setLastName(string last){
    lastname = last;
}

int getAge(){
    return age;
}

string getName(){
    return firstName + " " + lastname;
}
private:
    string firstName, lastname;
    int age;
};
```

Here is my main

```
int main(){    

DLinkedList list;
Person * ryan= new Person(19, "Ryan", "Temple");
list.addFront(ryan);
list.printForwards(100);
}
```

This line of code is giving the program trouble.

```
if (current->elem->getAge() <= age)
```

The value of the elem is getting set to NULL.
When the current is initialized it is getting pointed to the correct Node.
However accessing current in the if statement sets its value to NULL.

Can someone please help me?

EDIT:
Here is the addFront function

```
void DLinkedList::add(DNode* v, Elem& e) {
DNode* u = new DNode;
u->elem = e;            // create a new node for e
u->next = v;                                // link u in between v
u->prev = v->prev;                          // ...and v->prev
v->prev->next = u;
v->prev = u;
}
```

Add front

```
  void DLinkedList::addFront(Elem& e)     // add to front of list
{
   add(header->next, e);
}
```

Comment: Huh? What do you mean by the value of elem is getting set to null? You seem to be saying that elem->getAge() is setting elem to null. However, a couple sentences later, you also say accessing current in the if statement sets its value to null. So which is it. If current is null how do you know elem got set to null?

Comment: Please put up the code for the addFront function. That is where the mistake is likely to be.

Comment: @iheanyi current points to the correct node, however when I access that element it's accessing it from NULL. If that makes sense

Comment: Not quite. You can't access anything at null. It seems you mean that current is NOT null and elem is null.

Comment: But anyway, like FrankM suggests, post the comment for addFront. If you're having a problem with elem being null, that's likely the source.

Comment: @iheanyi precisely! Current is not null but elem is null!

Comment: As I suspected. addFront passes header->next into the add function but before you put in anything either next is initialized to null (meaning all that is done to v in add won't have any effect and will be violating memory at address 0) or next is initialised to a node with elem uninitialized or null.

Comment: @FrankM - no, that's not it. It's because the temporary Elem reference goes out of scope. next is initialized, likely in the DLinkedList constructor.

Comment: Looks like the DLinkedList constructor code is also needed for the full picture

Comment: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please. This is neither complete nor verifiable.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

My answer is incorrect. Something else is going on but without more source code, we can only speculate. As this is the accepted answer, I cannot delete it. So I've removed the original content from being visible as to not confuse others who may stumble upon this question.

Comment: Elem is typedef Person*

Comment: @FrankM Still, when you pass the "object" Elem to a function which takes it by non-const reference, the function gets a temporary object since the compiler needs to construct a new object and get a reference to that object. I've edited my answer to add the non-const reference part as that's the crux of the matter.

Comment: A reference to a pointer works exactly like a pointer but let's you modify the value of the original pointer. There is no problem with temporary objects anywhere in the code.

Comment: @iheanyi I removed the & from AddFront and Add and it worked!

Comment: @FrankM a reference works kinda like a pointer but it is not a pointer. In particular, because ryan was not originally a reference, it needs to be converted to one. That's where the temporary object creation comes from.

Comment: It's late and I need to go to sleep but I'll leave one more attempt at convincing you. int a = 10;  int& b(a); int c = b;  The result of this is a is 10. b is a reference to the same memory that contains a. c gets the value of a i.e. 10. Regardless of what happens to a or b the value of c will be 10 until it is changed again. Replace int with pointers and the same will hold true.

Comment: @FrankM Sleep on it. Just because b is a reference to a, doesn't mean if you copy the address of b, you get the address of a.

Comment: @iheanyi Yes it does! :-)

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou then explain the issue the OP had and why my "solution" worked.

Comment: I suspect the OP posted a simplified version of the code, and that the actual code involved more function calls in a way that caused a variable to go out of scope. There is no temporary being created here. In fact, temporaries can't be bound to non-const references.

Comment: @RyanTemple After reviewing this, I must agree with others that something else is going on and my answer is wrong. Can you un-accept it so I can delete the answer.